# Xcode Address Sanitizer with ccache

Tags: xcode, xcode8, address-sanitizer, ccache

I'm trying to use the Address Sanitizer in Xcode, but I'm also using ccache to accelerate my builds. To do this, I've set the `CC` flag at the Xcode-project-level to point to a script I'm storing at `~/projects/support/cmake/ccache-clang`. The script reads

```
#!/bin/sh
if type -p /usr/local/bin/ccache >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  export CCACHE_CPP2=true
  exec /usr/local/bin/ccache "${DEVELOPER_DIR}/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang" "$@"
else
  exec "${DEVELOPER_DIR}/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang" "$@"
fi
```

so the desired effect is achieved (ccache is used if installed on the dev's system). This is working well.

Now the problem comes when we turn on the Address Sanitizer for a given scheme. The build completes successfully, but then we finally see this error when we try to run:

```
Error: Check dependencies

Could not determine version of clang to find its Address Sanitizer library: ~/projects/support/cmake/ccache-clang
```

Perhaps this is due to some hacky implementation in Xcode where it tries to parse the compiler's path to determine the version?

Wondering how I can modify my script to allow Address Sanitizer to work. The current work around is to remove the overridden `CC` flag when we need to do sanitizer work.

Using Xcode 8.3.1

Answer (score 2):

Link the  Asan library directly instead of the checking the box in the scheme.

The linker *and* compiler flags should contain the following.

```
-fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer
```

If it cannot find the library, find the path to the asan dynamic library which is usually in

```
${CMAKE_LINKER}/../../lib/clang/version/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib
```

and add it to linker flags.

- [What's the proper way to enable AddressSanitizer in CMake that works in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44320465/whats-the-proper-way-to-enable-addresssanitizer-in-cmake-that-works-in-xcode)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make it work. Tested with Xcode 14.2

1. The script `ccache-clang` must be renamed to `clang` and `clang++` (i.e. `clang++` is copy of `clang`). It seems that Xcode first of all tries to detect compiler's name: clang, gcc, etc., so naming the script like this makes Xcode to decide that this is clang. Also I use `CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_` properties to set `CC`, `CXX`, etc.:

```
set(CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_CC         "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/clang")
set(CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_CXX        "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/clang++")
set(CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_LD         "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/clang")
set(CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_LDPLUSPLUS "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/clang++")
```

2. Libraries which are necessary for sanitisers must be copied into bin directory during CMake configuration. Something like:

```
set (_toolchain_root "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain")
# I tested on iOS/Simulator
file (GLOB_RECURSE _asan_libs
      "${_toolchain_root}/*/libclang_rt.*an_ios*_dynamic.dylib")

foreach (_asan_lib IN LISTS _asan_libs)
  file (RELATIVE_PATH _asan_relative_to_toolchain
        "${_toolchain_root}/usr/" "${_asan_lib}")
  configure_file ("${_asan_lib}"
                  "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/../${_asan_relative_to_toolchain}"
                  COPYONLY)
endforeach ()
```

After this I was able to enable sanitisers from Xcode, compile and run the app.