# What's the proper way to enable AddressSanitizer in CMake that works in Xcode

Tags: c++, cmake, clang, address-sanitizer

I've added AddressSanitizer flag as follow:

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fsanitize=address")
```

Everything builds and runs fine when using `Unix Makefiles`.

The problem comes when generating the Xcode project, it just doesn't want to link because it cannot find the ASan library.

I already found two solutions, but decided not to use them because they cannot be automated using just CMake:

1. Adding `-Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup` to the linked flags, so it skips linking to dynamic libraries.
2. Link with `libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib` directly.

So what's the problem with these two solutions?

- When using solution #1, I have to manually open the target scheme in Xcode and add `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES` environment variable pointing to `libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib`.
- When using solution #2, the path for the ASan library varies between computers.

Additionally as another solution, I tried enabling Address Sanitizer flag from the Xcode target scheme but interestingly it didn't detect the issues I added, so I didn't list this as a solution because it failed my test.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: maybe check this out: https://github.com/arsenm/sanitizers-cmake

Comment: If you know of an Xcode project setting that turns on what you want, you can set it from CMake by populating `CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_...` variables or using the per-target properties `XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_...`.

Answer (score 102):

The idea of this solution is to pass `-fsanitize=address` to the compiler and linker flags.

If you would like to enable this for all your targets at the same time, you can use [add_compile_options](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_compile_options.html) and [add_link_options](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_link_options.html). This makes sense if you have multiple, potentially a large of, targets.

```
add_compile_options(-fsanitize=address)
add_link_options(-fsanitize=address)
```

Alternatively, you can also use [target_compile_options](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_options.html) and [target_link_options](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_options.html) to set these for a particular target. This might make more sense if you do not want this to apply to all the targets.

```
target_compile_options(asan-target PRIVATE -fsanitize=address)
target_link_options(asan-target PRIVATE -fsanitize=address)
```

Comment: Just tried this it builds but no errors detected... When I build the same code using the line `g++ test_with_leak_main.cpp -fsanitize-address -g -std=c++20 -lpthread -static-libasn` it reports the memory leak.

Comment: Keep in mind ASAN needs to be compiled/linked with Clang and _not_ ld.

Comment: I used the first form but had both as `$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:-fsanitize-address>` so it will only be enabled for debug builds.

Comment: When using the commands for a particular target (a library that gets linked against from other targets), I had to use PUBLIC instead of PRIVATE, or I'd get linker errors.

Answer (score 41):

You need to provide the flag(s) to the linker too. I'm doing it like this:

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fsanitize=address")
set (CMAKE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG} -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fsanitize=address")
```

Comment: The second line looks wrong to me. Eight it should be CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG on both sides, or CMAKE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG.

Comment: set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fsanitize=address")

worked for me on iOS CMake builds. You should make sure to be using the correct configuration of the library that you build(Debug/Release)

Comment: Modern CMake: `string(APPEND CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG " -fno-omit...")`

Comment: @Timmmm Fiddling with `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` directly is not a modern CMake whatsoever. Use of `check_cxx_compiler_flag` would be closest.

Comment: @mloskot a) I was only talking about how to append to a string, and b) `check_cxx_compiler_flag` only checks if a flag is supported - you still need to actually add it!

Comment: @Timmmm Well spotted. Thank you. I made copy & paste mistake. I meant `target_compile_options` instead, of course.

Comment: Ah yes that is indeed cleaner, however in this case it requires you to apply it to every target, which is rather tedious.

Comment: @Timmmm: you can use add_compile/link_options to apply it to every targets. But this answer is the wrong way to do it these days. Just added the correct with cmake these days. Please find the answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70272150/2682142

Answer (score 24):

I propose create your own Asan profile.

```
get_property(isMultiConfig GLOBAL PROPERTY GENERATOR_IS_MULTI_CONFIG)

if(isMultiConfig)
    if(NOT "Asan" IN_LIST CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES)
        list(APPEND CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES Asan)
    endif()
else()
    set(allowedBuildTypes Asan Debug Release RelWithDebInfo MinSizeRel)
    set_property(CACHE CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE PROPERTY STRINGS "${allowedBuildTypes}")

    if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE AND NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE IN_LIST allowedBuildTypes)
        message(FATAL_ERROR "Invalid build type: ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}")
    endif()
endif()

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_ASAN
    "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG} -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer" CACHE STRING
    "Flags used by the C compiler for Asan build type or configuration." FORCE)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_ASAN
    "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer" CACHE STRING
    "Flags used by the C++ compiler for Asan build type or configuration." FORCE)

set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_ASAN
    "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG} -fsanitize=address" CACHE STRING
    "Linker flags to be used to create executables for Asan build type." FORCE)

set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_ASAN
    "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG} -fsanitize=address" CACHE STRING
    "Linker lags to be used to create shared libraries for Asan build type." FORCE)
```

**Notes:**

1. AddressSanitizer (ASan) for Windows with MSVC is under experimental stage thus I didn't provided the MSVC way here.
2. `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` isn't used by multi-configuration generators (Xcode, Visual Studio, etc), thus I provided an example to check this first.
3. The default value for `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` is an *empty string*. And user can set `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` to any value at the cmake command line. Therefore, we check both cases, and make sure that we are dealing with a known build type (if provided).
4. There is also `CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS` you may want to configure.

**Usage:**

```
$ cmake \
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Asan \
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: While this seems a bit complex compared some other answers, it does seem to be the best way to do it. Did you get this info from the book Professional CMake, by chance?

Comment: Yes, I adopted this from the book.

Comment: Anecdotally, this worked for me with cmake version 3.16.3 (and `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)`)

Answer (score 12):

cmake 3.13
introduce configuration for [xcode schema](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/release/3.13.html#id3)

in CMake

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
set(CMAKE_XCODE_GENERATE_SCHEME ON)
set(CMAKE_XCODE_SCHEME_ADDRESS_SANITIZER ON)
set(CMAKE_XCODE_SCHEME_ADDRESS_SANITIZER_USE_AFTER_RETURN ON)
```

When Build

```
xcodebuild -enableAddressSanitizer YES
```

Answer (score 5):

First ensure with debug info, such as <del>setting `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` to `Debug`</del> passing `-g` flag for GCC/Clang.

Then, if your target is an executable or an shared library, then you may set those cmake variables:

- `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS`
- `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG`
- `CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS`
- `CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG`

i.e. When your target is an executable:

```
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Debug")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG} -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fsanitize=address")
```

When your target is an shared library:

```
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Debug")
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG} -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fsanitize=address")
```

However, when your executable relies on an static library and you'd like to use asan to check your static library, then you have to set like this:

```
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Debug")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG} -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fsanitize=address")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fsanitize=address")
set(CMAKE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG} -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fsanitize=address")
```

Answer (score -2):

The simplest solution that I currently found is

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=ASAN .
```

I prefer this option since it expresses the intent (run sanitizers) rather than modifies a number of flags.

I do not know when this option was added. I also cannot find any documentation to it.

Comment: What version of CMake are you using? I can't find any meaningful reference to `ASAN` in the current CMake source code.

Comment: Maybe the reference is this: http://www.stablecoder.ca/2018/02/01/analyzer-build-types.html

Comment: The provided link, @MartinGerhardy, says at the very top that it is outdated.

Comment: This seems to only work for projects that directly query build type or do something like [this `FindASan.cmake` script](https://svn.ec-nantes.fr/eXlibris/Util/cmakeUtil/FindASan.cmake)

Comment: not working for my cmake 3.18.0 with `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)`