# How to enable sanitizers for Visual Studio projects via CMake?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, address-sanitizer

I need to set address sanitizers for my Visual Studio project via my CMake file. I can't make use of the GUI option for enabling sanitizers in VS since I need sanitizers to be enabled in my CI/CD flow.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44320465/whats-the-proper-way-to-enable-addresssanitizer-in-cmake-that-works-in-xcode